# c# accdb не могу добавить запись

Tags: c#, oledb

в базе accdb такая таблица  **people**

```
name1   name2   name3   birthdate  ....
```

у всех полей в свойствах "Обязательное поле - нет, Пустые строки - да"
соединяюсь с базой

```
static string connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = D:/123/db.accdb";
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connStr);

private void qry(string q)
        {
            conn.Open();
            OleDbCommand cmnd = new OleDbCommand(q, conn);
            cmnd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmnd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }
```

пытаюсь добавить строку

```
try{    
   qry("insert into people set name1='" + name1_ + "', name2='" + name2_ + "', name3='" + name3_+"'");
   }
catch (Exception exc) {
    MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
}
```

Получаю "Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement"
где ошибка? и как получить более подробное описание ошибки sql?

Comment: Все нужные запросы к базе можно с комфортом отладить в самом же Access.

Comment: @Bulson мне нужно работать через программу-клиента

Comment: Работать вы можете в дальнейшем как угодно. А вот заранее создать правильные запросы, протестировать их работу нужно в самом Access.

Comment: Вероятно, в ваших переменных `name*_` содержатся символы, которые нужно экранировать. Проверьте, какой sql-запрос у вас получился, выведя его на консоль или в лог в начале метода `qry`. Чтобы навсегда забыть о таких ошибках, используйте _параметры_.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov способ `insert into people(col1,col2, ...) values(val1, val2, ...)` работает. почему то `set` ему не нравится